# Difference between low impedance fuel injector and high impedance fuel injector

Tags: resistance

In my recent project ECU, I'm working with 4 stroke auto rickshaw. Here, when I check fuel injector properly, then I found out something like 3 Ohm written on it. So, I basically google it then I found, my fuel injector is low impedance fuel injector. And there are other high impedance fuel injector also available and it's resistance range is between 11-13 Ohms.

Now, what this resistance indicates ? And what is difference between this low impedance and high impedance fuel injector ?

Comment: Short answer: Resistance indicates nothing. Impedance heavily depends on the number of windings around the core, and this only slightly correlates to resistance.

Comment: Long answer: Always talk about impedance when you mean impedance. You generally have to use an injector with an impedance matching your driver circuit. Using a 12 Ohms impedance injector on a 3 Ohms driver circuit will fail it to open because of too few power transferred, and vice versa it will make your driver circuit overload.

Comment: This is the answer for your question http://performancefuelsystems.com/InjectorCompattibilitywithECUs-TechCorner.htm

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, the impedance allows you to work out you how much current it will take to make it open. Because an injector is a solenoid, it presents an inductive load rather than a simple resistive one, so the power consumption will be defined by the impedance, frequency of operation and the amount of time it spends open.

Low impedance injectors open and close more quickly but take more power to operate. They tend to be used for larger engines, or smaller ones with forced inductance, where the requirements for fuel flow are higher. They also tend to take a higher current to make them open but less current to hold them open, while high impedance injectors take the same current to open and hold.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your injector is really an injector or a solenoid valve. The high impedence injector will be more slow, and will use less fuel (the engine will have less power, or maybe polute less?) The source device should have a matching imdedence:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_matching